# What does the "@" symbol mean in Bazel?

Tags: bazel

I'm studying Bazel building system at present. I always see the @ symbol in Bazel script, but I cannot find any documentation about it. I searched it on the website of Bazel but the result seems useless.
[@ in Bazel](https://docs.bazel.build/search.html?cx=012346921571893344015%3Axv_nfgpzbu4&cof=FORID%3A10&ie=UTF-8&q=%40). 
For example:

```
filegroup(
name = "toolchain_fg",
srcs = [
    ":cc-compiler-amd64",
    "@x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu_gcc_730//:compiler_components",
    ],
)
```

Could anybody explain the @ symbol here for me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is to reference a remote repository.

From the doc, [depending on other Bazel projects](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/external.html#depending-on-other-bazel-projects)

> ```
> local_repository(
>     name = "coworkers_project",
>     path = "/path/to/coworkers-project",
> )
> ```
>
> If your coworker has a target `//foo:bar`, your project can refer to it
>   as `@coworkers_project//foo:bar`.

See also the [design doc of remote repository](https://bazel.build/designs/2015/07/02/skylark-remote-repositories.html) and [bind example](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#bind_examples) in workspace rules.

Comment: What about when `//` comes right after the `@` symbol, as in `@//foo:bar`?

Answer (score 1):

In Bazel, targets are referred by labels.

Bazel labels have the following format:

```
@repoName//packageName:target
```

For example, in the following packages found in `myRepo`:

```
 myRepo
    ├── WORKSPACE
    ├── package1
    │  └── BUILD
    │  └── src
    └── package2
       ├── BUILD
       └── src
```

a target called `myTarget` in `package1/BUILD` can be labeled as as `@myRepo//package1:myTarget` globally.
If referenced from the same repo, for example from `package2/BUILD`, then the `@myRepo` prefix can be omitted and you can use `//package1:myTarget`.
If referenced from the same package, for example in another target from `package1/BUILD`, then the package name can be omitted and you can use `:myTarget`. The colon can also be omitted if it does not create confusion with a name. Such short form labels should not be confused with the names. Labels start with '//' or ':'. But names never do. For example, the name of the first package is `package1` but its label is `//package1`.

Reference: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/build-ref.html